# State does not seem to be updated correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a list of star wars movies I have watched. I want to have the capability to check and uncheck what I clicked and have it saved by localStorage.
For some reason, sometimes, if I cross more than one movie at a time, after I refresh the page, only the last one i crossed remains crossed. I tried to debug with my console, and I see that the fault is with my state. Sometimes, after I click more than one element, some of them will stay false, instead of turning true.

this is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
export default class Movie extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super()
        this.state = (localStorage.appState) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.appState)
        : { 0: false, 1: false, 2: false, 3: false, 4: false, 5: false};
    }

    clickedTitle = (event) => {
        if (event.target.tagName === "SPAN") {
            this.setState({
                [event.target.id]: !this.state[event.target.id]
            }, () => {
                localStorage.setItem('appState',JSON.stringify(this.state))
            });
                // localStorage.clear()

            }
        }
        render(){

            return(
                <div className="sw_title"  onClick={this.clickedTitle}>
                <span id={this.props.index} className={`${this.state[this.props.index] ? "clicked" : "not-clicked"}`}> {this.props.title} </span>
                </div>
                );
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance for your precious time!
April

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am able to tell you are doing this on each singular Movie element. Being that every time you set the same localStorage Item to a new value of a single movie (being your state for given Movie component only holds value for one instance). It would be a better practice to keep state management outside Movie component, say in MovieS and only do presentational work in a Movie

```
import React from 'react';

export default class MovieS extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.state = (localStorage.appState) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.appState)
      : { 0: false, 1: false, 2: false, 3: false, 4: false, 5: false};
    }

    clickedTitle = (event) => {
      if (event.target.tagName === "SPAN") {
      this.setState({
          [event.target.id]: !this.state[event.target.id]}, () => {localStorage.setItem('appState', JSON.stringify(this.state))
      });
          // localStorage.clear()

      }
    }

    render(){
        this.props.movies.map( (movie) => (

            <Movie 
            click={clickedTitle}
            className={this.state[movie.id] ? "clicked" : "not-clicked"}
            title={movie.title}
            />

        ))

    }

}

function Movie({ click, className, title }) => (
  <div className="sw_title"  onClick={click}>
    <span id={this.props.index} className={}> {} </span>
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There should be **a single "source of truth"** for any data that changes in a React application and you are repeating `appState` in every Movie component which leads to inconsistent app state.

What you should do is to lift the state up. In other words, move that state and `clickedTitle` function to their parent component and pass `clickedTitle` as a prop to the Movie Component. (or you could use [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html))

More about [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)